# Encrypting web.config with aspnet_regiis works on local machine but fails when deployed to server

Tags: .net, api, iis

I have a web api application where i have encrypted the web.config using aspnet_regiis.exe. The application builds and works properly on my local machine but fails when deployed on remote server. It throws a runtime error saying the current custom error settings from this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error disable the custom error and enable detailed error in iis by following below steps:

1)Open the IIS manager.

2)Select your site. double click on “Error Pages”

[image]

3)Right click and select the “Edit Feature Settings…” or select the same from the Actions pane (in the right hand side)

[image]

4. Select the “Detailed errors” radio button and click on OK

[image]

refer below article for more detail:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dtkwfdky(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)